# xDB Tracker Timeout with certain contacts only

Tags: xdb, xconnect

Interesting behavior here with Sitecore XP 9.3, any ideas are very welcomed.

**What happens**

Only for specific contacts, anything related to Tracker reading (Eg: IdentifyAs, LoadContact, etc) is dying with a timeout, but only on CDs, while it normally works on the CM (We use SQL shared sessions on the CDs)

Eg:

```
Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs(source, value.ToString());
```

> Error: xDB unavailable - StackTrace: at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func2 func)
> at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.b__0()
> at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func1 operation)
> at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.LoadContact(String source, String identifier)
> at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.LoadContact(String source, String identifier)
> at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession.GetContactByIdentifier(String source, String identifier, ContactManager contactManager, Action`1 validateIdentifier)
> at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession.GetContactByIdentifier(String source, String identifier, ContactManager contactManager)
> at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession.IdentifyAs(String source, String knownIdentifier)
> at ASP.contactidentifyas_aspx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)

> Error: Operation was cancelled by timeout

Now comes the interesting part:

1. if I [increase the Tracker Timeout](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/configure-the-tracker-s-xconnect-client-api-timeout.html) to a high number (say 2 minutes), and run the same IdentifyAs code, instead of timeout, the identification will occur normally
2. After that, even if I decrease the timeout back to 5 seconds, this contact will not give a timeout again! And the IdentifyAs method runs pretty fast, by the way.

Looks like something large was stuck for this contact, and the IdentifyAs method when successfully completed is cleaning the contact.

Please let me know your ideas on how to attack this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For scenarios such as this, if you are running a load balancer, it is sometimes worth experimenting with toggling sticky sessions in order to isolate variables. However, since you are using shared SQL sessions, I don’t believe that would be helpful in this particular case.

Otherwise, such timeouts can indicate that large data payloads are at play. Do you have any untracked pages set in your configuration? If not, perhaps you should. If your site makes many XHR calls, that can add up quickly and clog up the pipes. More reading:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/web-tracking.html#untracked-pages_body

I also have a blog post about how to test issues like this more easily:

https://sitecore.marcelgruber.ca/posts/xconnect-rapid-interaction-spoofing-contact-identification

Comment: Hi Marcel! Yes, we have added untracked pages as well, but it was a recent change. Some contacts are still with the timeout issue, and I am more interested in explaining this "selective slowness" and, most important, to "fix" those contacts so they can start to be tracked again. It's curious how I managed to fix it by increasing the timeout, but this is not acceptable in prod (we can't force visitors to wait for 2 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

This could be explained if the contact being identified has a large number of interactions. Then when that contact is loaded the volume of data being called via API takes time to load.

To identify contacts like this try running the following:

```
SELECT TOP (100) ContactId, COUNT(ContactId) as Count
FROM [xdb_collection].[Interactions]
GROUP BY ContactId
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

Then analyse the data using below:

```
SELECT TOP (100) *
    FROM [xdb_collection].[Interactions]
    WHERE ContactId ='xxx'
```

More info here:
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0417184

Comment: That would not explain why everything started to get fast and the timeouts disappeared after increasing the timeout and the first successful identification. The same contact became faster and the interactions are all intact

Comment: Thinking better, maybe this could explain if the Interactions table has a flag for non-processed interactions.

Thanks for your answer Dean, I will run the queries and let you know of the results.

Comment: I'm thinking when a contact is identified for the first time, there are additional tasks that happen (for example merging other anonymous contacts). If the same contact is then identified again, perhaps these additional processes (and loading of interactions etc) doesn't happen so no delay

Comment: @RodrigoPeplau If this happening only for certain contacts and if you are aware of such a contact then maybe query against the ContactFacet table to know the details stored and compare with a "normal" one

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay I've done so, they don't have anything beyond average, and more strangely they will become fast again after the first successful IdentifyAs. Only when it times out, the next attempt will also be slow, and after the very first success, all subsequent attempts will be fast as well.

Comment: Can you please confirm the exact situation you are recreating (see here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/identifying-contacts.html). Is contact anonymous? Does contact id in session exist in XDB, does the identifier exist in xDB against a different contact ID? Please review table at bottom of link and confirm which situation best matches. Also when you say subsequent calls to identifyAs are faster, is that in the same session after first identify?

Comment: @RodrigoPeplau And do you witness this behavior for only selected contacts all the time like first request slow then fast while for others always fast. Or is this behavior randomized, like 1 request some contacts slow then fast, new session another set of selected contacts slow then fast

Comment: @DeanOBrien not a lot of interactions - around 800 max.

The situation is not present in your document:
- Contact in session is anonymous.
- Contact in session exists in xConnect as a known contact.

When I say the subsequent attempts will be fast, I mean not only in the same but also in different sessions

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay, not a random behavior, this happens to some contacts only

Answer (score 0):

Seems the connectivity between your CD servers and the xConnect server was not stable. Maybe when a website was running and sending the information to xConnect from which CD servers didn't receive the response in a timely manner.

It doesn't mean the xConnect getting any problems or errors.

If your xConnect is hosted under IIS in a separate application, you can try to look at its **App Pool settings**. Try to change the `Start Mode` to `AlwaysRunning` and `Idle-timeout Action` to `Suspend`. This can prevent IIS from terminating the xConnect when it reaches the `Idle-timeout` (20 minutes as default).